# Fix a div when scrolling down a page and then un-fix

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a sidebar div sit below a header secion, when you scroll down, it will turn into a fixed div and stay fixed until the bottom of the page, once it reaches a footer section, it will stick to the top of it and allow me to scroll down the footer area without seeing it anymore.

There is a perfect emaxple of what I am trying to describe on this site http://madebymany.com/blog/apples-aesthetic-dichotomy

In the left column, it sticks as you scroll down and then un-sticks at the bottom

I am looking for a good way to do this, hopefully an example or tutorial, I realize it is done with javascript changing the divs properties.  I have tried searching but all I could find was old outdated articles over 5-6 years old and they only did  half the job.  I am not sure even what to call this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That web site is using [jQuery Scroll Follow](http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/).

Note that according to the jQuery Scoll Follow web site...

> The Scroll Follow object will remain inside its immediate container.

... hence why the scrolling stops before the comments on your example web site; the element which is scrolling on the page is constrained inside of its parent `<aside>` element. [You can check out the example.](http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/sf-example-3.html)

Answer (score 0):

You basically handle the page's `scroll` event and move the box around.

Most tutorials require jQuery, so get familiar with it. If you want a tutorial, here's a working one: http://designwoop.com/2011/01/how-to-create-a-jquery-sticky-sidebar/.

Why not dissect the code of that website too?